# Two trains problem

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been doing these train problems lately and I am stuck at a problem that I can't figure out.

1. Two trains start moving at the same time towards each other from point $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$, respectively.
2. They meet at a point and after that one reaches the dest in $1$ hour and the other takes $4$ hrs.
3. How fast is one train compared to the other ?.

Note that one is leaving from $\mathbf{A}$ towards $\mathbf{B}$ and the other from $\mathbf{B}$ towards $\mathbf{A}$.

Comment: does the question really ask "How fast is one train from the other" ? What does that mean ?

Comment: Yes that's what it asks.How fast is one train running than the other?

Comment: Clarify your question and also give some distances

Comment: @anonymous look if you don't know the answer ,it's fine...but don't down vote a correct and complete question.

Comment: @Reckoner Your question is unclear. Also, I wasn't the person who downvoted you'll see the second downvote as proof

Comment: @WW1: I presume it would mean the relative speed, but this may be a typo of 'far' on the OP's part

Comment: It's not unclear.i will show you the screenshot later and that will be a proof that the question is complete.

Comment: Even if you show a screenshot showing the printed question, it won't prove anything. If a question is unclear, it's unclear.

Comment: You have ${\large 4}$ unknowns: 1) distance $\overline{\mathbf{AB}}$, 2) meeting point, 3) and ( $\texttt{2}$ ) train velocities and just two 'knowns' ( $1$ and $4$ hours ). So ?.

Comment: -1 point for being an argumentative jerk who refuses to acknowledge that a question is unclear, and insisting if others don't understand they must be downvoting.   "How fast is one train from another" is not a meaningful phrase.  If you showed me it printed on the front page of the new York times it still wouldn't be meaningful.  You could have asked far cl as rufucation of ab obvious typo but instead you argue and blame others for having reading comprehension.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing the question to something that makes more sense to me. "How fast is one train compared to the other?" is what I think the question is really asking for. Of course, it's more precise if the question had asked for the ratio of the speeds.

Comment: I have your post upvoted and requested as re-open.

Comment: @deepak yes that's what I meant...I thought it was obvious.....if not,i accept my mistake...but still I am of the opinion that this question might be unclear but it's not incomplete.You proved it....

Comment: @mick thanks Mick ..I know there is so much to learn from this problem..

Comment: No problem, I'm adding a vote to reopen as it's a fairly interesting elementary problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem can be solved to find the *ratio* between the speeds of the trains.

Let the first train have speed $v_1$ and let it take $1$ hour to reach the other terminus after the meeting. Let the second train have speed $v_2$ and let it take $4$ hours to reach the other terminus after the meeting.

The distance travelled by train $1$ to the meeting point is therefore $4v_2$, and that travelled by train $2$ to the same point is $v_1$.

The time taken to reach that meeting point from their respective starting points is the same.

Hence, $\displaystyle \frac{4v_2}{v_1} = \frac{v_1}{v_2}$, which gives us $v_1 = 2v_2$.

So one train is twice as fast as the other.

Comment: Yes that makes sense.....thanks a lot.......

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I would solve the question. Let the speeds of the trains be $v_1$, $v_2$, and suppose they met t hours after starting. Let train 2 reach 1 hour later, and train 1 reach 4 hours later.

Then, distance covered by train 1 in time $t$ hrs=distance covered by train $2$ in time 1 hr

And,
distance covered by train 2 in time $t$ hrs=distance covered by train $1$ in time 4 hrs

Hence, $v_1t=v_2*1 $
and $v_2t=v_1*4 $

Hence, dividing LHS by LHS and RHS by RHS, $\frac{v_1}{v_2}=\frac{v_2}{4v_1}$

$\frac{v_1}{v_2}=\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 2):

If one train takes one hour to reach a destination and the other takes four, the relative speed is simply 4:1; one train is four times as fast as the other.

Comment: read the question carefully...It's obvious that if one takes 1 hr and the other takes 4hrs,then the speed ratio will be 1:4.After they meet at a point,from that point onwards they take 4 and 1 hrs respectively.

Comment: @Reckoner Please clarify what you mean by "how fast is one train from the other" then.

Comment: @Reckoner Clarification on the way?

Comment: Suppose they meet at the centre of the  distance between and after that they take same time to reach their destinations.That means both were running at the same speed.But here it says that after they meet at a point,they take 4hrs and 1 hr resp.Here the given answer is :one train is running just twice as fast as the other.So that means if one was running at 50km/hr then the other was running at 100km/hr

Comment: @Reckoner Oh I see what you mean now, it wasn't possible to do without a distance measurement then. With that answer, the distance will be 300km

Comment: That is the problem.No data is provided in the question.I have been banging my head for this problem for 2 days now.After that only,i decided to post....just for some down votes 

Comment: @Reckoner Maybe you should add the distance of 300km to your post.